# Find git root directory in key mapping

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, plugin-fzf

I would like to find the git root directory and use it as argument for `:FZF` in a key mapping like this:

```
nnoremap <Leader>eg :FZF `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`<CR>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. If I understand it right, backtick expansion works only when vim expects a filename. I think `:FZF` expects a folder name but maybe vim doesn't know this.

How can this be done?

Comment: See `:help system()` and consider experimenting with https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#advanced-customization.

Comment: Thank you. I'm coming closer. At least `nnoremap <Leader>eg :echo system(['git', 'rev-parse', '--show-toplevel'])<CR>` works as expected.

Comment: Feel free to publish an answer to your own question. You can also accept it two days after posting to help other with the same problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`system()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#system%28%29) function to run an external command and take its output (as you realized, per your own comments.)

Furthermore, you may also need [`trim()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#trim%28%29) around it, to strip the whitespace (more specifically, the trailing newline at the end of the output from the command.)

You can then use [`:execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) to assemble a call to the `:FZF` command, passing the git worktree root as an argument.

Putting it all together:

```
nnoremap <Leader>eg :execute 'FZF' trim(system('git rev-parse --show-toplevel'))<CR>
```

Comment: Then I was already close to it but the `trim` was missing and the error message didn't help me understanding this. Thanks a lot!